# React Native Callkeep integration with Firebase notification getting stuck once cliking on Answer Button, How to skip callkeep VoiceConnectionService?

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, videocall, 100mslive

I'm working on **react-native-callkeep** integration with firebase FCM notification.
Callkeep integrated, and I'm getting call notification once triggering FCM notification as you can see the screen
[CallKeep Notification Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RE5sp.jpg)

But when app is in killed/quit or background state and i'm clicking Answer button in real Android device, App getting stuck.

Once I debugged the code in Android-Studio I found this log

```
D/RNCallKeep: [RNCallKeepModule][onReceive] ACTION_ANSWER_CALL 
V/RNCallKeep: [RNCallKeepModule] sendEventToJS, eventName: RNCallKeepPerformAnswerCallAction, bound: true, hasListeners: true args : { NativeMap: {"withVideo":false,"callUUID":"b52560f4-2360-4c69-8b05-7530a1b7b2fe"} } 
D/RNCallKeep: [RNCallKeepModule][onReceive] ACTION_AUDIO_SESSION 
V/RNCallKeep: [RNCallKeepModule] sendEventToJS, eventName: RNCallKeepDidActivateAudioSession, bound: true, hasListeners: true args : null I/ReactNativeJS: 'answerCall', 'b52560f4-2360-4c69-8b05-7530a1b7b2fe' 
D/RNCallKeep: [RNCallKeepModule] backToForeground, app isOpened ?true 
I/TelecomFramework: VoiceConnectionService: answer TC@13_1: CS.an->H.CS.an@AAA 
D/RNCallKeep: [VoiceConnection] onAnswer(int) executed 
D/RNCallKeep: [VoiceConnection] onAnswer called, videoState: 0, answered: true 
D/RNCallKeep: [VoiceConnection] onAnswer() executed 
D/RNCallKeep: [VoiceConnection] onAnswer called, videoState: 0, answered: true 
D/RNCallKeep: [VoiceConnection] onStateChanged called, state : 6 
D/RNCallKeep: [VoiceConnection] onDisconnect executed 
D/RNCallKeep: [VoiceConnectionService] deinitConnection:b52560f4-2360-4c69-8b05-7530a1b7b2fe
D/RNCallKeep: [VoiceConnectionService] stopForegroundService
```

I think once I'm clicking on Answer button then it starts communicating with TELECOM_CONNECTION_SERVICE, and once it's not founding any connection with telecom services then app getting stuck.

My callkeep integration code is like this

```
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
  console.log('Message handled in the background!', remoteMessage);
  displayIncomingCall(remoteMessage);
});
```

And

```
export const displayIncomingCall = remoteMessage => {
  const {data} = remoteMessage;
  const {customer_name, telephone} = data;
  const uuid = uuidv4();
  RNCallKeep.displayIncomingCall(
    uuid,
    `${telephone}`,
    `${customer_name}`,
    'generic',
    true,
  );
};
```

Once Clicked on Answer Button that time added EventListner

```
export const answerCall = ({callUUID}) => {
  console.log('answerCall', callUUID);
  invokeApp({data: notificationData});
};
```

I want to skip this VoiceConnectionService step
and once I click on answer button then app come to foreground
and pass some data while envoking the app from HeadlessJS Event to foreground APP.

Answer (score 0):

Add RNCallKeep.backToForeground():

```
export const displayIncomingCall = remoteMessage => {
 const {data} = remoteMessage;
 const {customer_name, telephone} = data;
 const uuid = uuidv4();
 RNCallKeep.displayIncomingCall(
   uuid,
   `${telephone}`,
   `${customer_name}`,
   'generic',
    true,
 );
  RNCallKeep.backToForeground()
};
```

Comment: Could you spend some time and explain your answer.